# PHP/JS Ajax _POST Array not Posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, regex

there's something strange going on in my ajax code.  I'm have some difficulty narrowing it down.

JavaScript:

```
//Discard Displaying Cards
$(".discard").click(function(){
    var gameId = 20;
    var cardArray = [];
    $( ".card" ).each(function() {
        var cardId = $(this).attr('id');
        cardArray.push(cardId);
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './system/actions/discard.php',
        data: "gameId=" + gameId + "&cardArray=" + cardArray,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(cardArray);
            console.log("Success.");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

The javascript posts to a file discard.php where it is given two parameters: gameId and cardArray.  gameId is static right now, but cardArray is made up of the DOM ids of each of the ".card" elements loaded on the page.  Each DOM id reflects the card_id in my database.

discard.php

```
//Classes
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/system/classes/cards.php';

header("Content-Type: text/html");

$gameId = empty($_GET['gameId']) ? '' : $_GET['gameId'];
$numbers = empty($_GET['cardArray']) ? '' : $_GET['cardArray'];


$regex = preg_replace('/[^,;a-zA-Z0-9_-]|[,;]$/s', '', $numbers);
$cardArray = explode(",", $regex);

foreach ($cardArray as $cardId) {
    discardCards($cardId, $gameId);
};
```

The discard.php is supposed to read the $_GET headers from the ajax request.  But for some reason, it fails.  The funny thing is, if I call the page directly with manual GET headers, e.g I browse to:

domain.com/system/actions/discard.php?gameId=20&cardArray=["1","3"]

OR even

domain.com/system/actions/discard.php?gameId=20&cardArray=1,3

The script works fine!
I thought it may have been something with the format ajax is posting in, hence the regex, but alas, it did not work.  Because I'm not even sure how to display or view the requested ajax data URL on the page it called on, I'm finding it particularly difficult to debug.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: console.log("gameId=" + gameId + "&cardArray=" + cardArray);

Comment: returns:  "gameId=20&cardArray=2,4" ... but like I said before, the discard.php doesn't read it correctly from the AJAX.  Because I can manually go to "/system/actions/discard.php?gameId=20&cardArray=2,4" in my browser and it makes the correct database changes.  However, from the AJAX source page, it doesn't make the database changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using:

```
type: 'POST',
```

But you are receiving it as `$_GET`, change it to `$_POST`:

```
$gameId = empty($_POST['gameId']) ? '' : $_POST['gameId'];
$numbers = empty($_POST['cardArray']) ? '' : $_POST['cardArray'];
```

Or change the AJAX function to:

```
type: 'GET',
```

And also, the `data` is supposed to be a string. So use `serialize()`:

```
$(form_id).serialize();
```

Where `form_id` is the `id` of the form.

Comment: Doh!  Changing it to $_POST fixed it.  Thank you.